# É possivel fazer um appendTo para outro documento?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom dia.

É possível fazer uma clonagem de uma div de uma página web para outa pagina?

Exemplo:

Acesso meu sistema e vou até a pagina "lista".

Nesta pagina lista, eu tenho uma div com id="testeConteudo".

Nesta mesma página eu tenho um botão que ao ser clicado abre uma nova página, chamada "editar".

Oque eu queria fazer era copiar o conteudo que eu digitei na pagina "lista" e ao abrir a página "editar" este conteudo aparecesse nessa nova página.

Dá pra fazer isso?

Obrigada

Answer (score 0):

Vou partir da premisa que ambas as paginas pertecem ao mesmo dominio, porém não necessariamente serão abertas na mesma aba.

na pagina lista você pode fazer algo como.:

```
var testeConteudo = document.getElementById("testeConteudo");
var editar = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-editar");

var onEditarClick = function(event) {
    localStorage.setItem('testeConteudo', testeConteudo.value);
}

[].forEach.call(editar, function (elem, indice) {
    elem.addEventListener("click", onEditarClick)
});
```

quando abrir a pagina de edição, você pode recuperar da seguinte forma.:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState === "interactive") {
    var testeConteudo = document.getElementById("testeConteudo");
    testeConteudo.value = localStorage.getItem('testeConteudo');
    localStorage.removeItem('testeConteudo');
  }
}
```

Comment: obrigado pelo exemplo, mas não funcionou. Vou pesquisar mais sobre isso. Preciso pegar o conteudo a pagina 1.html e jogar na pagina 2.html ... vou ver se encontro algo com JQuery.